# Tagging from Scratch: the Tag Cloud Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tagging, tag-cloud

I'm following the instructions from http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging and building a Tag System from Scratch. Everything are working great but not the tag_cloud helper. It raises database error while searching for tag_counts.

Following scope:

```
#Picture.rb

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :description, :title, :tag_list

  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings

#Because of the following I'm getting an error from the Posgresql (showed in "Database Error")

  def self.tag_counts 

    Tag.select("tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").
      joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id")
  end
end
```

## Application_helper.rb

```
def tag_cloud(tags, classes)
  max = tags.sort_by(&:count).last
  tags.each do |tag|
    index = tag.count.to_f / max.count * (classes.size - 1)
    yield(tag, classes[index.round])
end
```

## Database Error

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Pictures#index

```
PG::Error: column "tags.id" ​​should appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

LINE 1: SELECT tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count FROM "tags" I...

               ^
: SELECT tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."tag_id" = "tags"."id" GROUP BY taggings.tag_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group by tags.id, and/or count taggings.id

```
Tag.select("tags.*, count(taggings.id) as count").
  joins(:taggings).group("tags.id")
```

you can't group and aggregate at the same time in a query.

Comment: It seems to get the job done querying to the database, thanks! (Obrigado -> Português Brasileiro)

But it returns a String object to the Helper Method listed above in Application_helper.rb and I rolling into another issue: 

`**TypeError in Pictures#index**`


`String can't be coerced into Float`

Comment: That's a separate question. Put the expected results and the actual results in a new question (or whatever makes sense to isolate the problem), so everyone can have an opportunity to solve it. The database error has gone away, so this question is closed.

Comment: Thanks, its ok! I've got it right this morning. It was about this line `index = tag.count.to_f / max.count * (classes.size - 1)` that should be `max.count.to_i`. So obvious!

Comment: just post a new question on <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820413/tagging-from-scratch-the-querying-database-issue> and I have a feel that you can help. Thanks!