# Tagging from Scratch: the Querying Database issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on, jquery-tokeninput

@saverio was successful on answer this database query question on [Tagging from Scratch: the Tag Cloud Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806757/tagging-from-scratch-the-tag-cloud-issue/12808572)

Now I'm trying to connect the tagging system with the jQuery-tokenInput to **Create** and **Find** tags dynamically as on http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised.

- My guess is that is a Query problem to the Posgresql Database.
- I've got Postgresql correctly installed
- jQuery-tokenInput is on its place on *Application.js* `//= require jquery.tokeninput`
- Somehow it can load the tags from what was already on the database, but it fails querying the same words dynamically as listed below on *pictures.js.coffee* code.

Following all the relevant scope:

**`pictures.js.coffee`**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#picture_tag_tokens').tokenInput '/tags.json'
  theme: 'facebook'
  prePopulate: $('#picture_tag_tokens').data('load')
```

**`/views/pictures/_form`**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :tag_tokens, "Tags (separated by commas)" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :tag_tokens, data: {load: @picture.tags} %>
</div>
```

Here my logic get lost a bit

**`/models/picture.rb`**

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :tag_tokens
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  attr_reader :tag_tokens

  #The **below** is the relevant part for the #view/pictures/_form
  def tag_tokens=(tokens)
    self.tag_ids = Tag.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
  end

  def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by_name!(name).pictures
  end

  def self.tag_counts
    Tag.select("tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").
    joins(:taggings).group("tags.id")
  end

  def tag_list
    tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end

  def tag_list=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(",").map do |n|
      Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end
end
```

Below I could figure out that I'm not being able to query the Database

**`/models/tag.rb`**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :pictures, through: :taggings

  def self.tokens(query)
    tags = where("name like ?", "%#{query}%")
    if tags.empty?
      [{id: "<<<#{query}>>>", name: "New: \"#{query}\""}]
    else
      tags
    end
  end

  def self.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
    tokens.gsub!(/<<<(.+?)>>>/) { create!(name: $1).id }
    tokens.split(',')
  end
end
```

And so was how I set my Tags controller behavior

**`#controllers/tags_controller.rb`**

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @tags = Tag.all
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.json { render json: @tags.tokens(params[:q]) }
   end
  end
end
```

So, Why I can't Query the Postgresql and I'm not able to **Create** or **Find** Dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I incorporated a solution that's easy enough: using the Gem [ActsAsTaggableOn](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) with [jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

If you go through the algorithm below, you will figure out that the question above was just a misconception about the configuration between the Tag System and the jQuery. the following steps will help you in your path:

1 Put the jQuery Tokeninput files in the right places:

`Vendor > assets > javascripts > jquery-tokeninput.js`

`Vendor > assets > stylesheets > token-input-facebook.css (and 2 others)`

2 on the file in `apps > assets > javascripts > application.js` wright this line before //= require_tree . *this make the javascript work*

`//= require jquery.tokeninput`

3 on the file in `apps > assets > stylesheets > application.css.scss` wright before *= require_tree . *this make the css work*

`*= require token-input-facebook`

4 Put the `gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'` on your `gemfile` and run *bundle install* and the very same steps as [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging).

5 make a coustom route in `routes.rb` for a tag controller index (we are about to define) to enable the json property

`get '/tag.json', to: 'tag#index', as: :pictures_tags`

## The Following Code and the above allows us to talke properly to the database

6 run a `rails g tag controller index` and on this file wright the following:

> `#tag_controller.rb`
>
> def index

```
     query = params[:q]
     query = query.chomp(" ").downcase
     @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.where("tags.name LIKE '%#{query}%' OR tags.name LIKE '#{query}'")

if @tags.empty?
    ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_or_create_by_name_and_id(id: "#{query}", name: "#{query}")
else 
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @tags.collect{ |tag| {id: tag.name, name: tag.name } } }
    end
 end
```

> end

7 and finally glue everything with the code you will place on `app > assets > javascript > your_file_with_tags.js.coffee`

> `#your_file_with_tags.js.coffee`
>
> jQuery ->

```
$('#field_with_tag_list').tokenInput '/tag.json'

    theme: 'facebook'

    prePopulate: $('#field_with_tag_list').data('load')

    preventDuplicates: true

    resultsLimit: 3

    tokenLimit: 7

    tokenDelimiter: ","

    searchingText: "hit space for New Tag"
```

## PS: #field_with_tag_list is in your view(usualy _form partial) that you generates to impute the tags like this: (#controller_tag_list) i.e. #pictures_tag_list

`<div class="field">`

```
`<%= f.label :tag_list %><br />`

`<%= f.text_field :tag_list, data: {load: @picture.tag_list.map {|tag| { id: tag, name: tag }}} %>`
```

`</div>`

## All these are experimented code I'm sure that will help you =]

Answer (score 0):

Try at your controller:

```
  @tags = Tag.order(:name)
```

That's all.